# Arabic font saved incorrectly in SQL from the ِAdobe form

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, adobe

we are using adobe live cycle for our organization workflow, when the user enter a comment in Arabic in the form, the comments will be saved incorrectly in the DB "SQL 2008" , note the field is ntext

sample of text saved in DB

> ØªÙ Ø§ÙØ¬Ø§Ø²ÙØ§ Ø¨ØµÙØ±Ø© Ø³Ø±ÙØ¹Ø© Ø´ÙØ±Ø§ Ø¬Ø²ÙÙØ§  ÙØ³Ø±Ø¹Ø© ÙØ¯ÙØ© Ø§ÙØ§ÙØ¬Ø§Ø²

is there any way i can fix this text to be readable

thanks

Comment: "not the field is ntext" ?

Comment: What are you trying to insert? Can you recreate the problem with a simple example, e.g. `DECLARE @T TABLE (Col NTEXT); INSERT @T (Col) VALUES (N'Some text that fails');` - Also for what it is worth, [ntext , text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187993.aspx).

Comment: sorry @Magnus i meant note

Comment: when i am inserting using sql it worked and inserted correctly, the problem is with Adobe Live cycle form, when insert using the form, it will insert incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

Use NVARCHAR and Arabic Collation.

Read more here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/0cc7a320-9b7d-4781-bb3c-49861be682b1/arabic-collation-in-sql-server-2008-r2